# AT+HTTPACTION=1 not transmiting my datas I downloaded with AT+HTTPDATA

Tags: gprs

I'm using a SIM808 with arduino, and I want to send via a post request some data to a server using a php page that receive data via post requests, I'm using this AT commands but whenever I check my server I find a new blank column but not the data I send with my arduino, how can I solve this ? thank you

```
AT+CGATT=1

OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"Contype","GPRS"

OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","Free"

 OK
  AT+SAPBR=1,1

  OK
   AT+SAPBR=2,1

   +SAPBR: 1,1,"10.69.65.122"

   OK
   AT+HTTPINIT

  OK
  AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1

OK
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.php"

OK
 AT+HTTPDATA=18,10000
    var1=22D&var3=234D
   DOWNLOAD

   OK
   AT+HTTPACTION=1

    OK

  +HTTPACTION: 1,200,295
   AT+HTTPREAD

    +HTTPREAD: 295
    <br />     <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: var1 in <b>/storage/public_html/xxxxx.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />
```

**Notice**:  Undefined index: var3 in **/storage     /public_html/xxxxxx.php** on line **11**

and my PHP script : `

```
            // Include config file
             require_once 'config.php';
             $v1 = $_POST["var1"];
             $v3 = $_POST["var3"];

             $sql = "INSERT INTO rora (var1,var3)
             VALUES ('$v1', '$v3')";

             if ($link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
             echo "New record created successfully";}
             else {
             echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $link->error;
                   }

                $link->close();`
```

Comment: Gonna need to see your PHP script

Comment: Hi there, here's my PHP script